# How can I add array value into 2nd Combo Box model item getting the array name from 1st Combo Box selected item?

Tags: java

How can I add an array value into 2nd Combo Box model item, getting the array name from 1st Combo Box selected item?

```
String[] one = new String[]{"A","B"};  
String[] two = new String[]{"C","D"};  
String[] three = new String[]{"12500","13500"};
String[] four = new String[]{"Scale_1","Scale_2"}; 

private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String Value=(String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    DefaultComboBoxModel dm=new DefaultComboBoxModel(Value);  // here is the error
    jComboBox2.setModel(dm);
}
```

Error showing

> no suitable constructor found for DefaultComboBoxModel(String).

Answer (score 0):

This way you can get the selected item from the first combobox and add it to the second one, but I dont think you can get back the array name.

```
String[] one = new String[]{"A","B"};  
String[] two = new String[]{"C","D"};  
String[] three = new String[]{"12500","13500"};
String[] four = new String[]{"Scale_1","Scale_2"}; 

private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String value=(String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    DefaultComboBoxModel dm=(DefaultComboBoxModel)jComboBox2.getModel();
    dm.addElement(value);
    jComboBox2.setModel(dm); 
}
```